# Weird rendering with vis-network on react

Tags: vis.js, react-vis-network

I'm using vis-network on react / next.js.

When I go to a page with a network on it, the network appears in the top left corner, although the canvas fills out the entire screen (except for the navbar):

[image]

I have to click the same navbar item again to get the network in the middle of the screen.

Then there is another issue:
The nodes of the network often overlap, although there should be enough space. Any way to fix that?

### Try it yourself

The code is on GitHub, so you can clone and run the project:

```
git clone https://github.com/bennetrr/kafka-der-process.git -b feature/final
cd kafka-der-process/src
yarn install
yarn dev
```

The pages with networks on it are `Themen` and `Textsprache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problems myself.

For the first issue: Setting the size of the network manually and then calling `network.fit()` fixes the problem. The component now looks like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Network } from "vis-network";
import VisNetworkProps from "../types/VisNetworkProps";

function useContentDimensions() {
    const [contentWidth, setContentWidth] = useState(0);
    const [contentHeight, setContentHeight] = useState(0);

    const updateWidthAndHeight = () => {
        setContentWidth(window.innerWidth);
        setContentHeight(window.innerHeight - 50);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", updateWidthAndHeight);
        updateWidthAndHeight()
    });

    return {contentWidth, contentHeight};
}

export default function VisNetwork({nodes, edges, options, events}: VisNetworkProps) {
    const visJsRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [network, setNetwork] = useState<Network>();
    const {contentWidth, contentHeight} = useContentDimensions();

    useEffect(() => {
        const nw = visJsRef.current && new Network(visJsRef.current, {nodes, edges}, options || {});
        nw && setNetwork(nw);

        // Apply events
        nw && events && events.forEach(x => nw.on(x.event, x.callback));
    }, [visJsRef, nodes, edges, options, events]);

    network && network.setSize(`${contentWidth}px`, `${contentHeight}px`);
    network && network.fit();

    return (
        <div ref={visJsRef} style={{width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight}}/>
    );
}
```

For the second problem: I had the physics simulation disabled. Setting the `avoidOverlap` option to 1 on a solver, that doesn't move around with this setting, I get this code:

```js
const options: Options = {
    // ...
    physics: {
        solver: "hierarchicalRepulsion",
        hierarchicalRepulsion: { avoidOverlap: 1 }
    },
    // ...
};
```